# What is the difference between a compound noun and a collocation?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Compound nouns are usually two or more words put together to create a new noun.examples sunflower, blackboard etc. Where as collocations are words or phrases which are commonly used together. examples heavy rainfall, deep sleep, to make bed etc.Could you update me a little more about the same?

Comment: It's quite a big topic. What research have you done?

Answer (score 3):

> The *collocation* is a sequence or juxtaposition of words or terms that usually co-occur / go together in a sentence.
>   For example, you *make the bed*, but you *do your homework*.

Example :

1) collocations with *make* : *make breakfast*, *make a mistake*, *make a decision*, *make love*, *make room*, *make a noise*, etc.

2) collocations with *do* : *do the shopping*, *do the dishes*, *do your homework*, *do your hair*, *do a course*, *do a favour*, etc.

But *compound nouns* or *nominal compounds* are different things.

> More than one simple word or primary word or base word or root word combine together to form a compound word.

For example,

> (I) ready + made = *readymade* (compound adjective).
>
> (ii) full + fill = *fulfil* (compound verb).
>
> (iii) moon + light = *moonlight* (**compound noun** or **nominal compound**)

Compound nouns are also formed by simple words of different parts of speech :

> He (pronoun) + goat (noun) = he-goat (compound noun)
>
> Pick (verb) + pocket (noun) = pickpocket (compound noun)
>
> Over (adverb) + production (noun) = over-production (compound noun).
>
> Up (preposition) + keep (verb) = upkeep (compound noun).
>
> In (preposition) + come (verb) = income (compound noun).
>
> Draw (verb) + back (adverb) = drawback (compound noun).
>
> Hear (verb) + say (verb) = hearsay (compound noun).

Sometimes a compound noun consists of three words. Such compound nouns usually have the following structure:

> Noun + V-ing / V - p.p. + Noun.

e.g., *God-fearing person* ( = Person who fears God).

*Machine-made clothes* ( = Clothes made by machine).

Compound nouns can be written in different ways :

> 1) with no space between two words : *footpath*.
>
> 2) with hyphen : *tea-set*.
>
> 3) with space between the words : *mango tree*.
>
> 4) with hyphen between the first & the second words : *Tea-growing area*.
>
> 5) without any hyphen : *Calcutta bus routes*.

Comment: Nice answer. I am upvoting it

Comment: I am so thankful for what you've done.

Comment: A big thank for this answer

Comment: Not quite: if there is a space between the words, it's not a compound, e.g. "mango tree" is not a compound, but a syntactic construction consisting of head+modifier. Note that compounds are single words. "Tea-growing" is a compound, but the word "area" isn't part of the compound, but head of the NP "tea-growing area". And "God-fearing" is a compound, but "person" isn't part of it. It's head of the NP "God-fearing person" Further, compound nouns are not necessarily made up of different POS's, for example "ashtray", "pillow-case", "palm-tree", "cowshed" and many more are all noun+noun compounds.

Comment: In that case, are the word combinations like 'deep sleep ' and 'heavy rain' compound nouns or collocation?

Comment: @AltafJahangir "Deep sleep" and "heavy rain" are not compound nouns but syntactic constructions, more precisely noun phrases (typical collocations).  We know this because the first element can be modified, cf, "[very deep] sleep" / "[very heavy] rain". By contrast, the first element in a compound cannot be modified.

Comment: @BillJ, I have given the example of *noun + noun compound*, such as **"moonlight"**. Apart from this, compound nouns are made up of different POS's.

Comment: It's your statement "Compound nouns are formed by simple words of different parts of speech" that is misleading. It would help if you changed it to "**sometimes** compound nouns are formed by simple words of different parts of speech.

Comment: Separated words can form a compound noun, such as  *'cell phone', 'bus stand', 'railway station'*. These are used together so commonly that they're considered one term or one unit.

Comment: I'm answered. Many thanks

Comment: If the two words are separated they cannot possibly form a compound. A compound word is always a single word (sometimes hyphenated). "Railway station" is not a compound noun, but a syntactic construction consisting of "railway" (modifier) + "station" (head). We know this because compound nouns do not allow modification of the first element, whereas "railway station" does, c.f.  "[narrow-gauge railway] station".

Comment: *Compound words, modified words, new words. It's all the same. We think of compound words as two words joined together to make a new word with new meaning.* https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst4358_Compound-words-as-permanently-modified-nouns-.aspx

Comment: *A compound noun is a noun that is made with two or more words. A compound noun is usually [noun + noun] or [adjective + noun], but there are other combinations (see below). ... There are three forms for compound nouns: open or spaced - space between words (tennis shoe) hyphenated - hyphen between words (six-pack).*   https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm