# What is the difference between "compound noun" and "noun noun phrase"?

Tags: difference

I read:

> The *collocation* is a sequence or juxtaposition of words or terms that usually co-occur / go together in a sentence.
>   For example, you *make the bed*, but you *do your homework*.

Example :

1) collocations with *make* : *make breakfast*, *make a mistake*, *make a decision*, *make love*, *make room*, *make a noise*, etc.

2) collocations with *do* : *do the shopping*, *do the dishes*, *do your homework*, *do your hair*, *do a course*, *do a favour*, etc.

But *compound nouns* or *nominal compounds* are different things.

> More than one simple word or primary word or base word or root word combine together to form a compound word.

For example,

> (I) ready + made = *readymade* (compound adjective).
>
> (ii) full + fill = *fulfil* (compound verb).
>
> (iii) moon + light = *moonlight* (**compound noun** or **nominal compound**)

Compound nouns are formed by simple words of different parts of speech :

> He (pronoun) + goat (noun) = he-goat (compound noun)
>
> Pick (verb) + pocket (noun) = pickpocket (compound noun)
>
> Over (adverb) + production (noun) = over-production (compound noun).
>
> Up (preposition) + keep (verb) = upkeep (compound noun).
>
> In (preposition) + come (verb) = income (compound noun).
>
> Draw (verb) + back (adverb) = drawback (compound noun).
>
> Hear (verb) + say (verb) = hearsay (compound noun).

Sometimes a compound noun consists of three words. Such compound nouns usually have the following structure:

> Noun + V-ing / V - p.p. + Noun.

e.g., *God-fearing person* ( = Person who fears God).

*Machine-made clothes* ( = Clothes made by machine).

Compound nouns can be written in different ways :

> 1) with no space between two words : *footpath*.
>
> 2) with hyphen : *tea-set*.
>
> 3) with space between the words : *mango tree*.
>
> 4) with hyphen between the first & the second words : *Tea-growing area*.
>
> 5) without any hyphen : *Calcutta bus routes*.

---

But, I heard a friend calling "exam paper"  a compound noun. I don't agree with him since if it was a compound noun, then it must be combined together  as one word, like "sunflower," "blackboard" etc.

Also, although  "viewpoint" is combined together   as one word, I don't call it a compound noun since I can have it rewritten as "the/a point of view".

For me, I call each of these "Noun Noun Phrase"(NN phrase), but not compound nouns:

Viewpoint (view point) (it means "the point of view").
Newspaper( news paper) (it means "the paper of news).
Exam paper(it means "the paper of exam").
Copy paper(it means "the paper of copy").
Physics exam(it means "the exam of Physics").

Comment: It would've been clearer if you had mentioned that you copied the answer from this thread: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/249126/what-is-the-difference-between-a-compound-noun-and-a-collocation

Comment: The write-up about compound nouns at [this English Club page](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm) might help.

Comment: Why did you remove all others' comments into which many hours went!!!. ? I no longer see the comments which were being written.

Comment: Why did you, Eddie, remove all others' comments which many hours went into!!!. ? I no longer see the comments which were being written. –

Comment: BillJ, an Australian teacher of English said about your statement below  "No, that is incorrect. Where did you get that from? Compound nouns can be open (two words), hyphenated or closed (one word). Exam paper is a compound noun.  
 @ "If the two words are separated they cannot possibly form a compound. A compound word is always a single word (sometimes hyphenated). "Railway station" is not a compound noun, but a syntactic construction consisting of "railway" (modifier) + "station" (head). We know this because compound nouns do not allow modification of the first element, whereas "railway"@